# Chord confusion

Tags: theory, guitar

Total music theory noob here, taking my first steps to try and figure some of this stuff out. I have some sheet music for Wonderwall (for guitar), and I'm a little confused on one of the chords (see image below)[image]

So I've figured out from the key signature we're in the key of F#minor. I'm trying to figure out the notes in the B7sus chord, but the notes on the stave (B, D, A) aren't the notes showing in the tab above (B, F#, A, E, F#).

I'm sure it's just a case of me not really knowing how to read this stuff. I'd really appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, this music doesn’t at all reflect the way the members of Oasis actually played this song on guitar.

Comment: The sheet music in SMN looks like it is meant for piano, and the box diagrams above are for a guitarist to accompany.  A lot of song books are written this way and you need wor things out using the text as a guide.  It may be intentional, no reason for the guitar and piano to match exactly as long as they do not conflict.  Or it could be an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well spotted! The chords shown in the dots aren't exactly the same as those in the guitar chord windows. B7sus4 shouldn't have a D♮, there should be an E note instead.

That's a mistake. (By the way, that's not tab!). There is no obligation for either the guitar chord window or the music stave to show *all* the notes from a chord. But the chord name should be the correct one for that point. And the dots should reflect that.

As a keyboard and guitar player, I find this happening all too often.It's poor writing, and often I have to listen to what the rest of the players play, before deciding which is better to follow - chord name, chord window or actual dots.

Comment: Thank you - that's really helpful! Looks like it's something I'll have to watch out for (because it's not difficult enough already... :/ )

Just one more quick question. You mentioned the D# there, but I thought it was a D (it's not 'sharpened' in the key signature or on the actual note). I can see that in the key of B the 3rd is a D#  - is it something to do with that?

Comment: Well spotted again. I assumed (right or wrong) that since the chord mentioned was B.. not Bm.. that the D would be sharp. In B7sus, there wouldn't even be a D *or* a D#. There's a faint possibility that the chord could really be Bm11, which would just about cover all that's printed in that bar - but I doubt it... Don't think the Gallaghers were that advanced! Reckon they pressed a few strings down, liked the sound, and someone else had to transcribe it.  Lesson of the day - for me - pay more attention; for you - don't believe everything that's in print!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - really appreciate you taking the time here!

Comment: You say, *"B7sus4 shouldn't have a D♯, there should be an E note instead."*  But it is an E, look closer!  As the OP correctly said, the notes from the chord symbol  are B, F#, A, E, F#

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica - in the chord window, yes, but not on the stave.

Comment: @Tim - I don't get what you're saying. There isn't a D# anywhere on the page.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica - I've caused confusion - sorry. In the chord window there's an E, but on the stave there's a D (natural). That shouldn't be there if the chord is going to be a sus chord. That's what I meant.

Comment: Ummm ... Now I am confused. In the first sentence of your answer you mention D sharp. Did you mean to write D natural there?  You say, "B7sus4 shouldn't have a D♯" but who is saying that it should? Why have you mentioned D sharp at all? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica - edited accordingly! Sometimes I just have to prove I'm human - by erring... Thanks for spotting a schoolboy error. Possibly I was fixated by D#, as B7sus more often resolves to B(7), rather than Bm(7), if that makes sense.

Comment: IMO there's no _rule_ that the grand staff has to represent the same chords. It could just as well be a combination where the piano plays something a bit different. For example, a piano part could have voices going up and down and chords changing faster than is practical to write for guitar players. If the grand staff is a piano part. Chord symbols are an approximation, and it isn't _wrong_ to play something different. :)

Comment: @Tim Well, as far as how 'advanced' or otherwise it is to press some strings down and decide whether you like the sound, this is a tried-and-true compositional technique which I would imagine is responsible for a great deal of music, including some of great sophistication! Not least as the principle works as well on piano as on guitar, i.e. playing part "standard" major or minor chords and adding "extra notes". I'd say the piano part is a mistake though, as neither a determinate minor nor major tonality for that chord really seems to fit with the song. I would however say it's entirely

Comment: possible to alight on a m11 chord via the "pressing down some strings" process; in the original guitar part for Wonderwall the E and A at the top (frets 5 on B and E strings) are held throughout all four chords and the guitar is capo'd at the 2nd fret. Change the E to the D natural below and play the (capo'd) open strings from the 5th string onwards and you get a neat Bm11 voicing ;)